# Revit API transform "cannot access with an instance reference"

Tags: c#, revit-api

I'm experimenting with transforms. And trying to perform and store multiple transforms, but unable to probably due to the static property of transforms. Something like this:

```
Wall wall = doc.GetElement(id) as Wall;
BoundingBoxXYZ wallBoundingBox = wall.get_BoundingBox(doc.ActiveView);

//Original
Transform originalTransform = wallBoundingBox.Transform;

//Translated
Transform translatedTransform = originalTransform.CreateTranslation(wallBoundingBox.Min);
```

Error msg:
"Member 'Transform.CreateTranslation(XYZ)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead."

Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: according to http://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2018/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_Revit_Geometric_Elements_Geometry_Geometry_Helper_Classes_html] you need to use Operator* - Multiplies two specified transforms.

Comment: Interesting approach! I tried to test ways to get a transform using XYZs, but cant seem to find a way, any insights?

Comment: Sorry, not a system I've ever used, I was just reading API references...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CreateTranslation` is a **static member** of the `Transform` class.

Use it like this:

```
Transform translatedTransform 
  = Transform.CreateTranslation(
    wallBoundingBox.Min);
```

Comment: Is there any way I could store the translatedTransform in a variable, and perform another translation/ rotation on the variable instead?

Comment: It is already stored in a variable, in `translatedTransform`!